# How do i get the missing rows from a table compared to another table in different databases in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that have more than 200k rows, they are supposed to be identical except that one has 3 rows more than the other. I am trying to figure out which lines are they. And each table is in a different database. How can I do so in MySQL?

I tried this:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM db1.tb1 t1 
LEFT JOIN db2.tb2 ON tb1.col_13 = tb2.col_13 
WHERE tb2.col_13 IS NULL;
```

but it is taking FOREVER.

**EDIT**

Since col_13 is all duplicates, this wont work.
The problem is I cant find a commen primary key between the tables, the primary key between them is datetime, which is almost identical, but because of different scripts used to insert the data into each table, some of the rows have different seconds because of rounding, for example: "2015-09-01 00:00:11" and "2015-09-01 00:00:12" are the same rows but because of rounding they have different seconds.

Comment: I believe this will work, but you might want to extend to more join and where conditions if it is taking too long. If there is any duplicates in col_13 this is going to join on every single one of them. For example, if there is a duplicate value in both tables, you will have 4 resulting rows from the different combinations

Comment: The best practice is to join on a primary key column-- one that is filled with unique IDs, a timestamp, or equivelent.

Comment: okay the problem is col_13 is all duplicates, thats why its taking long time and wont work. The problem is the column that they share (datetime) is sometimes differnet as because of rounding; one will have 00:01:12 as time and the other 00:01:11 as time. But they should be the same. How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you thinking that the rows that are slightly different due to rounding should not be considered as missing? If so, you can use a DATEDIFF with missing rows being defined as those where the difference in minutes between col_13 in each table is greater than 1, for example.

Comment: How are these tables being filled?  Is it possible to fill the data in the tables at the same time in order to ensure the timestamp is correct? Additionally, how close are all the rows times from eachother. Would rounding the times cause issues?

Comment: If col_13 is all duplicates then there is no point in selecting on col_13.  That also explains why your query is taking so long: it is matching all 200K rows with all other 200K rows, and as a result is returning 200K*200K = 40 million records.  You have to come up with a join clause that actually differentiates between records in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easton's comments are correct.  You are executing the query properly.  Your issue isn't with joining two databases but with your query performance.  To solve that problem, more details about your table structure will be required.  His suggestions are good starting points though, namely make sure and do the join on a column which is unique and indexed in both databases.  That will allow the query to execute as quickly as possible.

If you can't easily fix the problem yourself, you may be best off asking a new question and this time focusing on the performance with more details about the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

This should take just a second or two since your query looks bang-on, so you may need to add indexes to col_13. If this only runs once or twice than you may not need that, but if it runs often, I would add indexes.